# Is the newline identifier (0a) put into the receive buffer when uart communication is performed?

Tags: msp432

When I am communicating with uart communication on a microcontroller msp432, I find that a value of 0x0a is added to both the sent and returned values, does this do anything?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBm9R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imZ6J.png)
After checking the ascll table I found that the value 0x0a corresponds to a newline, so will this value be put into the accept buffer, I found that after I add 1 to the value the return value is not 0x0a, but 0x0b, I am a little confused, so can someone explain to me how this works in detail?

Comment: Yes, it is doing just what it is supposed to. However, the MSP432 uses `"\r\n"`  (`0x13`, `0x0a`) for the line ending. (Ye old DOS line ending). The `'\n'` alone will simply move to the next line down, but not backup to the start of the line. That's where the carriage-return is needed (you remember typewriters don't you?) It would rotate the carriage-roller by one line-height (`'\n'`) return the carriage to the far-right so you could start typing the next charachter at the start of the next line. (`'\r'`). Add `'\r'` and all will be well.

Comment: (note: there is also a terminal setting -- depending on what serial-terminal you are using -- that will allow you to specify how line-ending are treated) E.g. PuTTY or x-term or minicom will allow you to customize how each line ending character is treated.

Comment: As far as having `0x0a` in the accept-buffer and adding `+1` and getting `0x0b` -- you are incrementing the character value in the buffer, not the pointer itself. Check your levels of indirection in that specific command. It appears you have *one-too-many* levels of dereference. Remember the `[ ]` (index) operator acts as a dereference just as `'*'` does. (e.g. `arr[i]` == `*(arr + i)`)